# gRPC web with react return value and asynchronous behaviour

Tags: reactjs, grpc-web

so I'm trying to call a simple backend service with react (FYI I don't know too much about react or javascript)

```js
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

const {EchoRequest, EchoResponse} = require('./proto/api_pb.js');
const {EchoServiceClient} = require('./proto/api_grpc_web_pb.js');
var echoService = new EchoServiceClient('http://localhost:8081');

function App() {
    var request = new EchoRequest();
    request.setMessage("Pew Pew Pew")
    let message = "initial value"
    echoService.echo(request, {}, function (err, response) {
        console.log(response.getMessage())
        message = response.getMessage()
    });
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo"/>
                <p>
                    {message}
                </p>
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

I'm trying to template the return value of `message` (which should have the value of echoService.echo's response)
but the app keeps showing "initial value" instead of the actual response type, even though it shows in the console

I know this has to do with some asynchronous behaviour, but I don't know how to wait for the request to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Changing a value like this won't trigger a re-render, that's why in `React` you can use state. If you change the state your component will re-render. This don't happen because you don't use state which results in your component showing the default value.

Here is a little documentation about how state works: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

To solve your issue you can use a React hook like this:

```
import {useState} from 'react'
const [message, setMessage] = useState("initial value")

// Do some stuff here

setMessage(response.getMessage())
```

This code obviously won't work out of the box but it shows the basics.